# Add a Custom Field in Comment Box next to the Text area in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Good Day.  I Recently try to figure out for adding the custom field in the comment box it working fine. Still I need to know how to add the custom field after the comment box. I am not sure how to do this.

add_filter('comment_form_defaults', 'change_comment_form_defaults');

```
function change_comment_form_defaults($default) {

    $commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();

    $default['fields']['comment'] .= '<p class="comment-form-author">' .
            '
<input type="checkbox" style="margin:0px;height:auto;width:auto; position:relative;" name="privacy" value="1"/> I agree to the Terms of Use and Privacy Policy</p>';
    return $default;
}
```

When i Tried this above code this way itself is appear. 
[image]

How can i do this to show this field next to the comment box.
Any suggestion would be great.

EDITED: 
[image]
Thanks,
vicky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `add_filter` with an `add_action` which happens just before the form closes, i.e by using the hook `comment_form`:

```
add_action('comment_form', 'add_input_privacy');
function add_input_privacy() {
    $commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();
    echo '<p class="comment-form-author"><input type="checkbox" style="..." name="privacy" value="1"/>I agree...</p>';
}
```

*You should give the function a more comprehensive name (add_input_privacy)*

Comment: I tried that i get this error .Cannot use a scalar value as an array in /home/domacq/public_html/techstumbling.com/demo/easywordpressscroller/wp-content/plugins/new/new1.php on line 19

Comment: +1 Thanks Nabil Kadimi For your Awesome Response. Here after I follow the Naming conversion of Function.

Comment: Actually the problem was in the function (the name is just for clarity) - As you can see it no longer works on an array like you did before, instead it generates output with `echo`

Comment: Which one is better when you call the function in hook like echo or return

Comment: That really depends on the situation, in your case you are 'adding' something, and not modifying(=filtering), thus `add_action` is more suitable, and since we are not modifying (=filtering), we don't have to `return`, we just do our action (`echo 'blabla';`) and don't care what happens next, this is different than `add_filter`, where you a have to return what WordPress Core or the plugin that implemented the filter expects. My explanation may be confusing, so please read this discussion here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/fliters-vs-actions-from-a-newbe

Comment: Hi Again I facing the Problem when i change the theme to twenty thirteen. I edited my question this is the output i get it now what shall i do now. . . Thanks for in advance.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35277/discussion-between-vicky-and-nabil-kadimi)